# Trying to pass x, y, z as parameters

Tags: c++

Error says expected primary expression before int on the line in main where I call foo. I don't understand and how to fix it. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(int *a, int *b, int c) {
    /* Set a to double its original value */
   *a = *a * *a;
    /* Set b to half its original value */
   *b = *b / 2;
    /* Assign a+b to c */
   c = *a + *b;
    /* Return c */
   return c;
}

int main() {
    /* Declare three integers x, y, z and initialize them to 5, 6, 7 respectively */
   int x = 5, y = 6, z = 7;
    /* Print the values of x, y, z */
   printf("X value: %d\t\n", x);
   printf("Y value: %d\t\n", y);
   printf("Z value: %d\t\n", z);
    /* Call foo() appropriately, passing x, y, z as parameters */
   foo(int *x, int *y, int z);
    /* Print the value returned by foo */
   printf("Value returned by foo: %d\t\n", foo(x, y, z));
    /* Print the values of x, y, z again */
   printf("X value: %d\t\n", x);
   printf("Y value: %d\t\n", y);
   printf("Z value: %d\t\n", z);
    /* Is the return value different than the value of z?  Why? */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Retagged to `C++` as this is not a `C#` question.

Comment: Further to the answers below, z is never actually read by foo in your code, it's a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling it incorrectly, you need to pass the address of the variables as the arguments:

```
foo(&x,&y,z);
```

Also, since you are passing z by value not reference, you should probably assign it to the return value of the function (it looks like that is what you are trying to do?):

```
z=foo(&x,&y,z);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring variables where you're meant to be passing them..

```
foo(&x, &y, z);
```